# Comma after an expression containing 'since'

Tags: punctuation, commas

I am a bit confused if I should use a comma in the folowing sentence:

> We can use this assumption since in our system, the rewards are bounded.

Comment: It's entirely a stylistic choice whether to put commas around the [optional] clause ***in our system***, but you'd have to use both or neither. Remember that commas really do nothing except reflect pauses in spoken contexts. Since you wouldn't *speak* the sentence with just one pause after ***system***, you don't *write* a single (unpaired) comma there.

Comment: You can use no commas: _We can use this assumption since in our system the rewards are bounded._ You can also use two commas: _We can use this assumption since, in our system, the rewards are bounded._ You could also separate the two clauses with the comma: _We can use this assumption, since in our system the rewards are bounded._ But the comma should not be used as in your example.

Comment: @FumbleFingers : That looks like an answer, not a comment.

Comment: @P.E.Dant : That looks like an answer, not a comment.

Answer (score 1):

> **Quote:** The main thing to aim for is clarity and readability.

You should ask yourself: Do you think a comma should be there? Is the sentence easier to read and understand with or without one?

I agree with `@FumbleFingers`. *You should either place a comma before and after the [optional] clause or place no commas at all!*

Your sentences is incorrect as is. Possible choices are `(according to @P.E. Dant's comment)`:

> - We can use this assumption since in our system the rewards are bounded.
> - We can use this assumption since, in our system, the rewards are bounded.
> - We can use this assumption, since in our system the rewards are bounded.

Comment: I guess your second choice **We can use this assumption since, in our system, the rewards are bounded.** builds the clearest sentence, so is the question of the OP, IMO. +1